# go hugo filtering a list from site.Data and .Params.object

Tags: hugo

```
  {{ print site.Data.test.list }}
  <br>
  {{ print .Params.list }}
```

```
[map[is_featured:true title:adf]]
[map[is_featured:true title:adsf]]
```

Why can I not use the where query on the .Params.list the same way I can with the data from site.Data.test.list

```
  {{ print ( where site.Data.test.list "is_featured" true )}}
```

Works ok

However

```
  {{ print ( where .Params.list "is_featured" true ) }}
```

throws the following

```
render of "page" failed: [1;36m"/Users/dev/repos/layouts/services/single.html:29:13"[0m: execute of template failed at <where .Params.list "is_featured" true>: error calling where: can’t iterate over <nil>  render: failed to render pages: can’t iterate over <nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your list is empty... that is what the error is saying. I am not sure WHY it is empty, because I cannot see your code.

Comment: How is my list empty if I can see the list is being printed out

Comment: I am just translating the error message for you. I do not know.